# How to remove nav-bar from custom magento admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

I want to remove navbar from a custom magento admin panel popup. I have already removed header and footer, but can not remove navbar panel.

Please help

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_xyz>


    <remove name="footer" />

    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="top.menu" />
    <remove name="top.links" />
    <remove name="top.container" />


    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="nav-bar" />
        <remove name="header" />
        <block type="core/template" name="xyz" template="abc/test/test.phtml" />
    </reference>


</adminhtml_catalog_product_xyz>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<remove name="menu" />
```

Your XML file will be

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_xyz>


    <remove name="footer" />

    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="top.menu" />
    <remove name="menu" />
    <remove name="top.links" />
    <remove name="top.container" />


    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="nav-bar" />
        <remove name="header" />
        <block type="core/template" name="xyz" template="abc/test/test.phtml" />
    </reference>


</adminhtml_catalog_product_xyz>
```

However, please note that as part of Magento admin controller, the following function will be called

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->_setActiveMenu()
```

That function will do this

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
```

Because we already removed that per the above XML, it will throw an exception.

To prevent this, override _setActiveMenu() in your controller 
(e.g. YourName/YourModule/controller/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php) by adding

```
protected function _setActiveMenu(){
    return false;
}
```

It should now work.